# Firebase Storage Download URL not working

Tags: firebase, api, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am currently trying to retrieve an image from my firebase storage, but the problem I encounter is that when I go to the images' link that I obtain from the function `getDownloadURL` when I am logged into the browser I get the image, but if I am in incognito mode I get a JSON object returned below as such.

```
{
  "name": "folder/folder/abc.png",
  "bucket": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "generation": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "timeCreated": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "updated": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "size": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "md5Hash": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "contentEncoding": "identity",
  "contentDisposition": "inline; filename*=utf-8''abc.png",
  "crc32c": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "etag": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>",
  "downloadTokens": "<REDACTED FOR STACKOVERFLOW>"
}
```

There are moments where I have gotten an image from the URL in incognito but it is very rare and inconsistent. Any idea what could be happening? I think the security rules are set correctly since when they weren't not even JSON was being returned.

I need it to return the image even when in incognito so that I can serve the link and people can see the image.

Answer (score 1):

It was an encoding issue. the `&` in the url from the `getDownloadURL` function was being converted to `/u0026` causing it to return json rather than the image.